# Google Analytics Reporting API V4 php fatal error

Tags: php, reporting, analytics

Dose anyone meet this error when calling $analytics->reports->batchGet($body); Please help me.

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   React\Promise\Promise::__construct() must be callable, null given,
>   called in
>   /path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/react/promise/src/Deferred.php
>   on line 25 and defined in
>   /path/to/google-api-php-client/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php on
>   line 16

Comment: This could be php version issue. my version is 5.4.19, but higher version to 5.4.45 it's work

Answer (score 0):

This could be php vision issue. my vision is 5.4.19, but vision higher to 5.4.45 than it's work